# How to create Gauss Plot from normally distributed values?

Tags: normal-distribution, graphing-functions

I have measured the loop time of some code which includes network transfer. The times differ from $15$-$40$ms and seems to be normally distributed.

I would like to plot a Gauss bell curve to have a visualisation. I searched for that term but only found solutions where you have certain values in a certain amount. Buy my times are all different albeit very close together.

Any ideas on how to create such a plot? I have Excel and Matlab available but am open to other solutions as well.

```
Example data extracted somewhere in the middle:
26.9749164581
26.9930362701
27.113199234
27.0140171051
27.0209312439
27.0221233368
27.0299911499
27.321100235
27.0371437073
27.547121048
27.755022049
27.932882309
27.1420478821
27.1480083466
27.1620750427
27.1768569946
27.1859169006
27.2240638733
27.2359848022
27.2669792175
27.2750854492
27.2948741913
27.3058414459
27.3599624634
27.3630619049
27.3728370667
27.3809432983
27.4407863617
27.4469852448
27.4569988251
27.4569988251
27.4610519409
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to plot a histogram, or maybe a density estimation. Excel, Matlab and co. have integrated functions for that. Or is there something more here? The result is not an exact Gaussian then though. If you want to extimate a Gaussian curve, then just take the mean and empirical standard deviation of your samples and plot the curve with them.

Comment: I think you are right. I am sorry that I dont know the exact mathematical terms for that. A density estimation sounds like what I am looking for